# Convert Drawable to res

Tags: android

I have a list of Drawable stored in a Array. Now I would like to convert it into "res"(int datatype). Is this possible? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Better thing is to explain what you want to do (beside this), so the community will better help you or will suggest workarrounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably trying to get a resID from a random Drawable. If so then this is impossible - drawable doesn't store IDs.

But if you use TypedArray to load your drawables from resources (i.e. `Resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.your_imgs)`) then you'll be able to get resID by calling `getResourceId(int index, int defValue)`:

```
TypedArray typedArray = mResources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.my_imgs);
int resID = typedArray.getResourceId(index, defValue);
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to modify the resources in an existing APK on the device.

Answer (score 0):

"res" is an identifier to access a resource packed in .apk file. So I think to "convert" drawable to res actually means modifing existing .apk on device, which is impossible

Answer (score 0):

if you have the drawable names in the array you can use

```
getIdentifier (String name, String defType, String defPackage);

int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("us","drawable","com.app");
```

The above function will return an integer value same as R.drawable.us.

This is how you access with resource names.